# WordPress. Неправильно отображаются ссылки на мессенджеры

Tags: php, wordpress

В админке выведены поля, куда можно вставлять свои ссылки на мессенджеры.

Если написать `tg://resolve?domain=` , то на странице будет `https://resolve/?domain=`. Так и в вайбере. Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что при выводе на экран ссылки очищаются функцией `esc_url()`, это нужно для обеспечения безопасности. В этой функции запрашиваются разрешённые протоколы, установленные в `wp_allowed_protocols()`. По умолчанию, список разрешённых протоколов такой:

```
$protocols = array( 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'irc6', 'ircs', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'sms', 'svn', 'tel', 'fax', 'xmpp', 'webcal', 'urn' );
```

Как и везде в WordPress, в данной функции есть фильтр, с помощью которго можно изменить список разрешённых протоколов. Добавьте в `functions.php` вашей темы такой код:

```
/**
 * Filters the list of protocols allowed in HTML attributes.
 *
 * @param array $protocols Allowed protocols.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_kses_allowed_protocols( $protocols ) {
    return array_merge( $protocols, [ 'tg', 'viber' ] );
}

add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', 'my_kses_allowed_protocols' );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Работает

Comment: Плюс, но я бы добавил "а ещё лучше - на основе этого сделать плагин, чтобы не потерять при смене темы" ;)

Comment: @SeVlad а ещё лучше - mu-plugin. Но я специально не вдаюсь в плагины, ибо создание плагина у многих вызывает замешательство.

Comment: Я к тому, что оставлять единственный вариант (причем не самый правильный) не совсем хорошо.. Нужно учить делать правильно, а ;)

Comment: @SeVlad я тоже за правильность, но всему в одном ответе не научишь.

Comment: Ну одна строчка лишней точно не будет. И главное не будет заблуждений - "вот так советуют спецы" ;)